# ArcGIS Server - Deleted service

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-enterprise

We are having a major issue. We are using ArcGIS Enterprise for our workgroup projects for multi-user editing. Long story short we had a project on a service and this morning it was gone. No trace of it whatsoever. I can't even find a file with the corresponding service name.

I'm trying to figure out what happened. Is there a way to check a log of activity? Such as seeing what happened to different services, changes, publishes, deleted services and so on?

This is a major problem in our office and we need to find out what happened and our periodic back-up does not cut it.

Comment: It's best practice to keep a a copy of all published McD's, organized in the same structure as your services, in case the Server is completely broken and needs to rebuilt. I've never seen a service spontaneously delete itself, with the rest of the site fully functional, so there may have been human error involved.

Comment: Don't know if this is still an issue, but is the service stopped? When a service is stopped then it won't appear at the rest/services end point. Is it possible that it's named something other than what you are looking for. I've heard of a service deleting it's self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is of course the ArcGIS Server log: Log into the ArcGIS Server Manager (https://yourserver/arcgis/manager), and click on the *Logs* button. Depending on the Log Level (Click *Settings*) you may or may not find anything useful.

Other than that, you might try the system's Event Viewer.

Comment: Hello Berend, and thank you for the quick reply. I did check the Server Log but unfortunately i came up with nothing. I did set up my log to Verbose level but it doesn't seem to register deleting services (did a test). As for the Event Viewer, it also doesn't say anything about deleting files or i couldn't find anything. I did search in the System events and couldn't find anything related.

Comment: @VladDumitrescu You can thank me by accepting this answer ;-)